# Workflow doen's send email to person field

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, lookup-column, email

I need to configure a workflow which would send an email on item creation to the user in `Person` field of that item.

So I've opened SPD, created a new workflow on that list, selected `Send an Email` from actions, specified `Person` as recipient.

Although, that person doesn't receive any email.

I've checked the workflow history, and there's an error:

> The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly.

When I specify an external recipient (just hard-code the email) everything works fine.

This is my recipient configuration:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing?

I need to get the email address from SPUser's `Work Email` property.

Comment: Can you debug it to see if the email address is valid? You should be able to log the value to the workflow history and view it.

Answer (score 4):

Just resolved my problem.

If you want to send an email to user in person field, the recipient configuration should look like this:

[image]