# Retrieve Person Field's Email Address in Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, email, person, workflow-lookup

I am having trouble getting a `Person`'s email address from a *Person or Group* column (named `SharePointUser`).  The `Person`'s email address is visible to me in the list itself, however, in the workflow all I can seem to get is the `Person`'s unique ID.

[image]

I have tried all the possible `Return field as` options and here is what I get:

```
SharepointUser As String: 540
SharepointUser Display Name: 540
SharepointUser Email Address: 540
SharepointUser Login Name: -1
SharepointUser User Id Number:  540
```

I also tried the suggestion [posted at this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/181828/4008), however, I get a `Workflow failed to get user profile for user:540`.

Grr.  Not sure why this is causing me such trouble!  I can see the email field *right there on my list!* Why are you hiding from me?!

Comment: Do you have the user rights, that you are using to log-in?

Comment: Please go in the Site Settings => Open the User Group Settings(From which User_group you are getting the User) => 
Who can view the membership of the group? is this Everyone?

Comment: @Ram - I went to `Site Settings: People & Groups: Group Settings` (for each group).  Some were set to "Everyone" and some not.  I changed them all to "Everyone".  However, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Which Workflow you are using? If you are using 2013 then use App Steps & 2010 use Impersonation Step. Hope it would be help you.

Comment: @Ram - It's a 2010 Workflow.  I will test that, however, I am the Workflow Author and a site owner and the creator of the list and the one initializing the workflow ...

Comment: Once you finished with the testing, Add comment here.

Comment: @ram - that didn't make a difference. I ended up adding another text column and copy pasting the email addresses from the Person column in bulk edit for the time being. Kind of silly but not sure what is causing this issue.